# Sudo error deleting TM backup

Tags: macos, backup, time-machine, mojave, sudo

I am trying to delete a TM backup on Mojave using sudo (this has worked in the past).

Any ideas why I'm now getting this error - apparently 4294967295 is a UID in the sudo command.

I get the same error trying to delete another backup in the list.

[image: Snapshot of backups and delete attempt]

sudo version:

```
Colins-MacBook-Air:~ Colin$ sudo -V
Sudo version 1.8.29
Sudoers policy plugin version 1.8.29
Sudoers file grammar version 46
Sudoers I/O plugin version 1.8.29
```

Comment: Thanks. I just checked - all up-to-date. No pending updates for Mojave. I tried other sudo commands - eg, "sudo ls" - same error, but "sudo -V" worked ok.

Comment: I don't have an answer to the problem, but a work around would be to use `sudo su` to get root and then run the command.

Comment: Unfortunately, when I try "sudo su", I get the same "sudo: 4294967295: invalid value" message :-(

Comment: Try running `sudo visudo` and see if the file shows and if it is corrupted in anyway.

Comment: :-( Same error: sudo: 4294967295: invalid value

Comment: I think you might be in operating reinstall territory now :( I am happy to give instructions but I can’t imagine you need it if you are using terminal for this.

Comment: Agh, I was afraid you might say that... something I was trying to avoid, of course. I was considering updating to Catelina. What do you think ; should I just bite the bullet and do that, which should fix the problem? Your instructions for the reinstall would always be useful... as, you may have some ideas, or a smoother approach than I have thought of.

Comment: I don't think I would bother with upgrading but just take a backup of the files (not time machine) and do a fresh install to Catalina.

Comment: Yes, I agree... I will wait until I get a spare moment in a few days (in case it takes longer than I hope for some crazy reason) and will go to Catalina. Thanks.